# Finding the maximal direct sum decomposition of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Suppose a matrix $M$ over some field $k$ allows a diagonalisation $P D P^{-1}$. On the level of linear maps, this is a decomposition of the linear map $f: V \to V$ represented by $M$ into

$$V \cong \bigoplus_{i = 1}^n k \xrightarrow{\bigoplus_{i = 1}^n f_i} \bigoplus_{i = 1}^n k \cong V,$$

where $f_i$ is defined by $x \mapsto M_{ii} x$ and the isomorphisms are represented by $P$.

We cannot always do this, so can we find a best approximation in the sense of a decomposition

$$V \cong \bigoplus_{i = 1}^m V_i \xrightarrow{\bigoplus_{i = 1}^m f_i} \bigoplus_{i = 1}^m V_i \cong V,$$

where we want $m$ as large as possible?

Comment: The Jordan normal form is probably what you are looking for

Comment: @SolubleFish For $k = \mathbb{C}$ that is exactly what I am looking for. But if $k$ is not algebraically closed, not every matrix admits a Jordan normal form if I recall correctly. Nevertheless, every linear map can be factored as I described because $m = 1$ is a trivial factorisation. Is there some kind of generalisation of JCF to other fields?